# yii2 inner join identityinterface

Tags: authentication, yii2

I'm learning yii2, so I wanna use identity interface after login, show all personal information of a worker, I have 3 tables: Users, Workers and Persons,
so after login I need get person data (name, lastname,genre,etc), so I'm using it:

```
public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    $user = Users::find()
    ->select("id,login,name")
    ->innerJoinWith(["workers","workers.person"])
    ->where("activate=:activate", [":activate" => true])
    ->andWhere("id=:id", ["id" => $id])
    ->one();
    return isset($user) ? new static($user) : null;
}
```

but, when I'm trying to get "name" in view I can't see anything, I'm using :

```
 <?= Yii::$app->user->identity->name?>
```

and value is null, 
what am I doing wrong?? it happens after successfull login.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because i can't testing it in this moment but try this way

```
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        $user = Users::find()
        ->select("id,login,name")
        ->joinWith('workers')
        ->where('workers.person' => $id)
        ->andwhere('activate' => true)
        ->andWhere('id => $id])
        ->one();
        return isset($user) ? new static($user) : null;
    }
```

however  the right value in Identity is username and not name

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->username
```

Comment: I have seen my query and the result is good: <br>SELECT "id", "login", "name" FROM "public"."Users" INNER JOIN "public"."Workers" ON "public"."Users"."idpersona" = "public"."Workers"."idpersona" INNER JOIN "public"."Persons" ON "public"."Workers"."idpersona" = "public"."Persons"."idpersona" WHERE (activate=TRUE) AND (id=1)  ; but in the model I can't assign in the attribute $name anything

Comment: Explain better. First the query  OK is the your or the mine?. second the problem with the model is a new one non mentioned in the question? If is so then update the question and add the info for the question about the model. Otherwise explain me

Comment: the query Ok is mine, the problem is when I'm doing innerjoin to get Person information, the query is ok, but the model doesn't recognize the attribute "name", so when I'm trying to call <?= Yii::$app->user->identity->name?> in a view, I can't see anything, the only attributes that I can see is from the table "Users", but not from "Persons"

Comment: attention is  Yii::$app->user->identity->username not name. I have update the answer anyway